# Branch maintenance in git

Tags: git, git-branch

I have a master branch and 3 other branches like b1 b2 and b3 .I have committed my code in master branch. I want that particular commit to be in branch b1 and b2. How to reflect that commit in b1 and b2

Comment: It depends. Either you've discovered that feature b1/b2 depend upon the change in master (in which case you should `rebase`) or that a variant of the change currently in master is a valid part of the feature, and shouldn't have been pushed to master in the first place, in which case you can `cherry-pick`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[git-cherry-pick](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick) - Apply the changes introduced by some existing commits.

1. Checkout branch b1, means, you should be in the branch, where you want the commit applied.
2. Do a `cherry-pick <commit-id of the commit in master branch>`
3. Push the changes to remote using, `git push origin b1`

Now the commit applied to the branch, which you checkout, then just push it to remote.

Comment: It will just cherry-pick that code to our local. But how to push that into branch b1 and b2 ? Because we will not have any git add option to add files for commit

Comment: @user1595186, Answer updated, you have to push the branch to remote

Comment: I'm not a fan of this; this likely means you will have two copies of the change in your history, depending on how it resolves. You probably want `rebase`.

Comment: @RJFalconer : He just want a particular commit to be in other branch

Comment: My point is that there's many methods to have a commit "be in" another branch. (e.g. as an ancestor? as current head?). For the average searcher `rebase` is probably what they want.

Answer (score 0):

[git-rebase](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase) - Re-parent b1 and b2 to be on top of the commit  in master.

1. `git checkout b1`
2. `git fetch master`
3. `git rebase master`
   (resolve any conflicts)
4. `git checkout master`
5. `git merge -no-ff -m "merging feature b1 into master" b1`